# query between dates mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi Im started in nodejs and mongo, I need a query between dates, I have a json with dateend and datestart and a var of name today, I need all files where today ids between datestart and dateend...this es my json:

```
{"userId" : "56385713381766175160105b", 
    "datestart" : "2020-09-04T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "dateend" : "2020-12-31T03:00:00.000+0000", 
    "promo" : true, 
    "promocion" : true,  
    "material" : "full"
}
```

I dont know how I can built the query, sorry for the mistake:

var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

```
Collection.find({
    datestart: {
        $gte: today
    },
dateend:{
 $lt:today
}

})
```

sorry Im just starting with this...

Comment: Don't you have those backwards?  `datestart >= today < dateend` ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `datestart <= today < dateend`?

Comment: yes sorry .(, well I wont see the structure